# How to create google workplace add-on for Drive UI integration "Open With Menu" and publish it in google workplace marketplace

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I started developing a Google Workplace add-on for my project, the flow is I need to install the add-on and access Drive permission once the permission is granted, then I need to enable "Open with Option" in my Google Drive and want to redirect the Google drive file to my app, how can I do it?

is there any guidance for this?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the guide:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-apps

Basically, create a gcp project, enable the drive api, enabled the marketplace sdk and then you can submit for review